# Excel VBA - Sending Group Message via Lync / Communicator API

Tags: vba, excel, lync, office-communicator

I am trying to send a group message to more than one user over Lync/Microsoft Communicator from Excel using VBA.

The below code works for a single e-mail address/user but if a cell range of two e-mail addresses is provided, it gives "Method 'CreateGroup' of Object IMessengerAdvanced' failed" error. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub sendIM()
 Dim msgr As CommunicatorAPI.IMessengerConversationWndAdvanced
 Dim msgTo As Variant
 msgTo = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2").Value
 msgr = Messenger.InstantMessage(msgTo)
 msgr.SendText ("Test")
End Sub
```

The InstantMessage(Object) method supposedly works for >1 user according to this previous topic below, but in practice it doesn't seem to...

[Lync notification of offline people using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192417/lync-notification-of-offline-people-using-vba/35705688#35705688)

Comment: I thinnk you need to send the list as an array....try changing this:Dim msgTo As Variant   to this:   Dim msgTo() As Variant

Comment: you may also need to change this:  msgTo = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2").Value to this:  msgTo = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2")

Comment: Thanks for both the suggestions, unfortunately neither worked, as I get the same error message.

Comment: try this? put 2 email addresses in here that work....instead of msgTo = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2").Value  try this: msgTo  = Array("email1@dot.com", "email2@dot.com")

Comment: The third suggestion worked perfect, thanks for your help!

Comment: I am not sure why the first answer did not create an array, but I am glad it worked out when explicitly creating an array. I will post the answer, below, because its kind of obscure

Comment: Do you think it could be a type casting issue when passing in the cell range as an Array? Ideally, I'd like to run the code using a list of e-mail addresses from an Excel range, rather than hard coding them in

Comment: I fixed up the code to convert a range to array variant, see if it works, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface expects an **Array** of email addresses when sending to a group.

instead of:

```
Sub sendIM()
 Dim msgr As CommunicatorAPI.IMessengerConversationWndAdvanced
 Dim msgTo As Variant
 msgTo = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2").Value
 msgr = Messenger.InstantMessage(msgTo)
 msgr.SendText ("Test")
End Sub
```

test this:

```
Sub sendIM()
 Dim msgr As CommunicatorAPI.IMessengerConversationWndAdvanced

 Dim msgTo() As Variant
 ReDim msgTo(0 To 0)                       'Allocate first element
 For Each cell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2")'put your range here
     msgTo(UBound(msgTo)) = cell.Value2          'Assign the array element
     ReDim Preserve msgTo(UBound(msgTo) + 1) 'Allocate next element
 Next
 ReDim Preserve msgTo(LBound(msgTo) To UBound(msgTo) - 1)  'Deallocate the last, unused element

 'sometimes you need to use Set, sometimes you dont, depending on environment you have, or maybe OPTION EXPLICIT
 Set msgr = Messenger.InstantMessage(msgTo)
 'msgr = Messenger.InstantMessage(msgTo)
 msgr.SendText ("Test")
End Sub
```

Comment: I adapted some work from here: http://superuser.com/questions/808798/excel-vba-adding-an-element-to-the-end-of-an-array

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked great. I only had to make one minor change "msgr = Messenger.InstantMessage(msgTo)" to "Set msgr = Messenger.InstantMessage(msgTo)" as it caused an error otherwise.

Comment: yes, the verson of VBA you use can sometimes require Set and sometimes prohibit Set. I think it has to do with the version or some other environment setting. or maybe if its in a mod or cls